# Most suitable approach for repeated tasks in Android background thread

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-handler, android-background

I'm writing an android application to mock GPS location. Its purpose is to help in testing and once it starts mocking it will be sent to the background. I need to execute a location update every `n` seconds and that needs to continue when the application is not visible.

I'm really confused by the different options of executing code outside the UI thread, the various recommendations about when each is most appropriate, which can / cannot be cancelled, and which can / cannot communicate data to the UI thread.

Can someone please tell me which approach will enable me to execute code periodically when my application is in the background and also satisfy the following requirements? I've tried to keep this general so that the question is not too specific to my problem.

1. can access data from the UI thread
2. can update data within the UI thread
3. can be cancelled
4. can itself schedule future work, e.g. when executing location update 1, schedule location update 2. when executing location update 2, schedule location update 3

Comment: Best practice is use custom `Service` class to update locations and use `ServiceConnection` to keep the service not to destroy and by binding service you can update or do your actions with data

Comment: Do you want it to run even after app is killed?

Comment: @HarikumarAlangode no, it can stop when the app is killed